# Out of memory errors while using Alteryx and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, alteryx

I'm getting "Error SQLExecute: out of memory for query result" while trying to load a mid level database (10s of millions records).

My Workflow is not doing anything that should cause it to store all the data in memory and the error appears to come from the Alteryx or the PostgreSQL driver.

Answer (score 1):

Deep within the [ODBC driver options](https://odbc.postgresql.org/docs/config.html) there is an option called "Use Declare/Fetch" which you should turn on.

To get there "Configure..." your named User DSN within ODBC Sources (see start menu) then "Options" > "Datasource" and tick "Use Declare/Fetch"